Можно ли как-то расширить переменную PATH в cmd Windows
Переменная PATH имеет максимальную длину 1024 символа. Значит в неё нельзя поместить все пути, которые хотелось бы. Вопрос заключается в следующем: если какая-то возможность расширить переменную PATH и если да, то как?


Переменная PATH имеет максимальную длину 1024 символа.

Это неверная информация.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/environment-variables?redirectedfrom=MSDN

The maximum size of a user-defined environment variable is 32,767 characters. There is no technical limitation on the size of the environment block. However, there are practical limits depending on the mechanism used to access the block. For example, a batch file cannot set a variable that is longer than the maximum command line length.

Т.е., согласно документации, лимит размера переменной составляет 32 кб. Остальные, более жёсткие, ограничения, устанавливают программы. Например, SET и SETX ограничивают вводимую длину значения 1023 символами. Прямая запись значения в реестр - 2047 символами. И т.д.
Возможные решения:

Установление значения из команды или скрипта PowerShell. Например, через SetEnvironmentVariable(..).

Использование переменных среды (их значение в переменной PATH расширяется общим порядком). SETX longpath="very long folder name" + SETX path=%path%;%longpath%.

Использование в PATH (если ФС поддерживает) 8.3 путей.



При запуске из командной строки вторая команда должна быть такой: SETX path=%%path%%;%%longpath%%, иначе переменные окружения подставятся ещё до передачи в SETX и чуда не произойдёт.

@PavelMayorov Угу... но я ж не готовый код пишу, а просто поясняю  суть происходящего.
